# Having both crashlytics and Google Analytics in the same apps

Tags: android, google-analytics, crashlytics

I'm using Crashlytics for bugs reports in my app, but I need some Google Analytics features, is it bad practice to have both, will it affect a lot my performance ( and life battery?)

I know it is kind of subjective, but what I need to know is if it is acceptable or not...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, they are totally made for different purposes. One is made for Crash Reporting the Other one is mainly about App Statistics (e.g Which view has been visited mostly in your apps etc.)

Regarding to performance concerns, It depends on how frequently you use them. E.g Crashlytics has that Custom Logging feature, to push Custom Logs along with Crash Reports and Handled Exceptions and Google Analytics normally is being called when you launch an `Activity` or `Fragment` to keep Page Statistics. But I don't think these should be a concern in terms of performance and power consumption.

As a result, I've used them in a couple of projects and I believe it's fine that you use them together.